# how to insert a line using into a file in alphabetical order using shell script

Tags: linux, shell, unix

How can i insert lines into a file using shell script such that they are inserted in alphabetical order, following would explain better.

input file contains :

```
1 hsdfd
2 bsdfd
3 ekksdf
.
.
```

i want to insert these contents into another file using shell script such that they are as below,sorted on the alphabetical order:

```
< root > <br>
< devices name="bsdfd" value=2 > <br>
 < details info="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"> <br>
 < details info="yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy"> <br>
< /devices > <br>
< devices name="ekksdf" value=3 > <br>
 < details info="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"> <br>
 < details info="yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy"> <br>
< /devices > <br>
< devices name="hsdfd" value=1 > <br>
 < details info="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"> <br>
 < details info="yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy"> <br>
< /devices > <br>
< /root>
```

Comment: containing the numbers, or are these only representing line numbers?

Comment: please edit your question to show (at least part of) what you expect the finished product to look like. Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
echo "1 hsdfd
2 bsdfd
3 ekksdf " | sort -k 2 

2 bsdfd
3 ekksdf 
1 hsdfd
```

So if there is a second file, and you want the result being sorted:

```
cat file1 file2 | sort -k 2 > sorted
```

#### updated: After your edit, I would use sed for the main work, after invoking sort:

```
echo "1 hsdfd
2 bsdfd
3 ekksdf" | sort -k 2  | sed -r 's/(.*) (.*)/foo \2 bar \1/;a\nyell\nprok'

foo bsdfd bar 2
nyell
prok
foo ekksdf bar 3
nyell
prok
foo hsdfd bar 1
nyell
prok
```

Some cosmetics with cat in the end, for footer and header. Done. :)

Comment: thank you for the solution, i slightly edited the question to reflect my actual scenario, kindly take a look..

Answer (score 0):

`sort -k 2,2 input.txt > output.txt`

See http://ss64.com/bash/sort.html

Comment: thank you for the solution, i slightly edited the question to reflect my actual scenario, kindly take a look..